# HTM table <td> width expansion difficulty

Tags: html, css

i have been having difficulties in this section of my web page, the  where you can see a lot of test words. What I am trying to do is to make the height of the td auto so whenever a message was submit its width won't expand. I've been limiting it width property but its not working, I have also tried having display block in css but it doesn't help at all, what is the best way to resolve this problem?
here is the image:
http://img209.imageshack.us/img209/4439/errrorx.png

this is my code for the table

```
<table  class="itemlist" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4">
    <tr class="det_msg">
        <td><?php echo $detail ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

here is my code for the css

```
.det_msg td{
    margin:6px; 
    width:920px;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #333;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    margin-left:100px;
    padding:50px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a table for this? It doesn't seem like you're displaying tabular data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution:

```
.itemlist {
    table-layout:fixed;
}

.det_msg td{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NkfNf/1/

but in actually, your problem is that you inserted an unbelievable long "word" (no white space) to that td. it hard for browser to break it right, so it wasn't broken, displayed in one line.

so that, better solution: make sure you won't display such a "long word" on web.

Comment: insert some white space. I can't figure out a scenario, could generate such a "long word", like thousands of characters.

Answer (score -1):

`<table class="itemlist" width="100%"...` <--- don't make it 100%, make it a value